Wix5 : CustomAction run at uninstall time too
In Wix 5
Why both actions are called both at install and uninstall ?
      <CustomAction Id="InstallConfigFile" BinaryRef="dllExecutionTest"
                    DllEntry="InstallConfigFile"            
                     Return="check"  />
      <CustomAction Id="UnInstallConfigFile" BinaryRef="dllExecutionTest"
                    DllEntry="UnInstallConfigFile"          
                     Return="check"  />
       <InstallExecuteSequence>
          <Custom Action="InstallConfigFile" After="InstallFiles"></Custom>

               <Custom Action="UnInstallConfigFile" After="RemoveFiles"></Custom>
       </InstallExecuteSequence>


In v5 the syntax has evolved has per below
<Custom Action="InstallConfigFile" 
         After="InstallFiles" 
        Condition="NOT Installed"></Custom>

<Custom Action="UnInstallConfigFile" 
        Before="RemoveFiles" 
       Condition='REMOVE="ALL"'></Custom>
       

